# Arduino Due PWM

Tags: arduino, pwm, arduino-due

I want to be able to use the Arduino Due PWM at higher resolution and frequency than what is available by default. I use IDE 1.6.8, that was the most recent a few weeks ago when I installed it (I think 1.6.9 may be on its way now). After searching on the internet and experimenting with the board and an oscilloscope, I got to the following conclusions:

- To get higher PWM frequencies, one has to modify the corresponding lines in *variant.h*. PWM seems to influence pins 6 included to 9 included, TC the other PWM enabled pins; I guess it is because of which pin is on which timer? It seems *micros()*, *millis()* etc are not affected by the modification:

`#define PWM_FREQUENCY    20000 // changed from 1000
 #define TC_FREQUENCY     20000 // changed from 1000`

- As said in multiple places, the *analogWriteResolution()* Arduino function is broken, or at least it is not sufficient on its own to increase the Due PWM resolution. For the *analogWriteResolution()* to work as expected, one also needs to modify the following in *variant.h*:

`#define PWM_MAX_DUTY_CYCLE  4095  // changed from 255
 #define PWM_MIN_DUTY_CYCLE  0
 #define PWM_RESOLUTION      12    // changed from 8`

- It seems that the physical labeling on the Arduino Due R3-E that is the standard when I bought my board is misleading: it is written on the board *DIGITAL (PWM~)* and such a *~* is present only on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11 while I can get PWM on all pins 2 included to 13 included.

I post this content here as it took me a while to figure out everything and to check on the oscilloscope etc, and I could not find those answers on stackoverflow. I also have two questions:

- Is it OK (as it looks like from the tests I did) to modify the PWM and TC frequencies? May it interact with other core functions / libraries?
- Is there a reason for the default values of PWM max duty cycle and resolution, other than backward compatibility?

Comment: It worked for my DUE! On my Win 10, i found two 'variant.h' files: C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.12\variants\arduino_due_x AND C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.12\variants\arduino_due_x. To be sure I changed booth of them as they were identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the PWM frequency divisors:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=16612#msg121031

This is implemented in the PWMfrequency library:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency
which basically looks like this:

```
void setPwmFrequency(int pin, int divisor) {
  byte mode;
  if(pin == 5 || pin == 6 || pin == 9 || pin == 10) {
    switch(divisor) {
      case 1: mode = 0x01; break;
      case 8: mode = 0x02; break;
      case 64: mode = 0x03; break;
      case 256: mode = 0x04; break;
      case 1024: mode = 0x05; break;
      default: return;
    }
    if(pin == 5 || pin == 6) {
      TCCR0B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | mode;
    } else {
      TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | mode;
    }
  } else if(pin == 3 || pin == 11) {
    switch(divisor) {
      case 1: mode = 0x01; break;
      case 8: mode = 0x02; break;
      case 32: mode = 0x03; break;
      case 64: mode = 0x04; break;
      case 128: mode = 0x05; break;
      case 256: mode = 0x06; break;
      case 1024: mode = 0x07; break;
      default: return;
    }
    TCCR2B = TCCR2B & 0b11111000 | mode;
  }
}
```